# how to use callback function before animation completes?

Tags: jquery

using callback function:

```
$('.caption').animate({'bottom':'0px'}, function(){$('.caption').text(data);});
// animates and change caption from image1 to image2
```

using callback function before animation

```
$('.caption').text(data);
$('.caption').animate({'bottom':'0px'}); 
//first change caption from image1 to image2 and animates
```

But I want to change the caption from imag1 to image2 during the animation.

Comment: You can use the `start` property to execute a function once the animation starts, alternatively you could set a timeout to occur at a specific time after the animation begins.

Answer (score 0):

One option would be to call the animation then set a timeout to change the text half way though:

```
$('.caption').animate({'bottom':'0px'}, 1000); 
setTimeout(function(){ $('.caption').text(data); }, 500);
```

Because the animation is set to 1000ms and the timeout at 500ms, then the text should change about half way thought he animation.

[Here is a working example](http://jsfiddle.net/ERgcw/)